# C# is there a difference between passing a struct reference and a class reference to a method in terms of speed?

Tags: c#, class, struct, pass-by-reference

As seen [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/how-to-know-the-difference-passing-a-struct-and-passing-a-class-to-a-method), structs are passed by copy and classes by reference. But why is passing a struct by reference using the ref keyword still slower than passing a reference to a class ?

I got different speeds for my program by replacing the `struct` keywords with `class`. All of the variables were already passed with the `ref` keyword.
By changing keywords, I got  20% speed increase in my tests. Shoudn't the speed remain the same since I was already passing by reference ? What am I not understanding ?

Comment: It would help if you could make a minimal example that demonstrates your observations, and post the code here

Comment: Passing a struct object with the `ref` keyword isn't the same as passing a class object. For instance, in the called method, if you assign a different object to a ref'd parameter, the variable in the caller points to the new object as well. But if you just pass a class object to the method, assigning a new object to the parameter doesn't affect the variable in the caller. It might be helpful for you to look at the IL generated by both methods to gain an understanding.

Comment: Have you read [Choosing Between Class and Struct](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/choosing-between-class-and-struct)?  Does your object meet all the characteristics mentioned in the bullet list?  I'm guessing it doesn't - which is probably why you find class to perform better.

Comment: thanks for the tip, I think I still lack understanding on how C# works at a very basic level

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Passing struct by `ref` is roughly the same as passing class by value (pointer to data), passing class by `ref` (pointer to pointer to data) should be a bit slower than passing class by value as extra dereference required.

Whether you get speed improvements or not from replacing "pass struct by value" to "pass struct by ref" depends on size of struct. If you follow [Microsoft's guidance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/choosing-between-class-and-struct) "size of struct <= 16 bytes" the difference will likely be insignificant anyway, otherwise if struct is huge you likely see some performance gains.

The potential gains/losses also depend on 32bit vs. 64bit (x86/x64) CPU architecture choice - measure carefully on target machines if performance is so important in your case.

Note: passing struct by ref generally limit choices of type to arrays and fields - make sure you are willing to live with such restriction.